# For Network traffic, what does the word "origin" mean to you?

Tags: networking, network-programming, cross-domain, terminology, user-experience

At my company, we often use the word "**origin**" to mean "**the place where all your content lives and where we send our network requests to get that content**." This does not seem to make sense to me, and I'm not sure that it makes sense to our prospective customers either.

For me, the concept of an origin being the place that things are sent TO is very non-intuitive... but I have not been in a networking/CDN field for very long, and I am trying to determine if this is an industry-standard definition.

**In other words: if I talk to someone who needs to configure internet traffic for their company's network, and I say "origin," will it mean to them what we THINK it means to them?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As far as discussions of networking in the particular context of the Web, the word *origin* is a term of art with a specific meaning, defined in [RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-5). It means a particular scheme/host/port triple, such that two URLs that have the same scheme/host/port triple are understood to have the same origin. So http://example.com and https://example.com do not have the same origin, because they have different schemes, and http://example.com and http://example.com:8888 do not have the same origin, because they have different ports.

That definition is most directly relevant to the Web because the entire Web security model is based on a well-defined ["same origin" policy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-3), but that said it seems like the underlying notion is useful for discussions in other contexts as well, because it amounts to considering things simply in terms of "a service on a particular host listening on a particular port and speaking a particular protocol".

Answer (score 2):

An origin is where something originates from. In networking, the origin of network traffic is the source of the network traffic. This may sometimes look backwards because of the request/response of many network protocols. For example, a network client receiving a web page originated the conversation by sending an HTTP request to the server, so it is the origin of the conversation, but the server is the origin of the web page.

The word origin in networking is really no different than the simple definition provided by [Webster's Dictionary](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/origin):

> **origin**
>
> noun or·i·gin \ˈȯr-ə-jən, ˈär-\
>
> Simple Definition of origin
>
> Popularity: Top 30% of words
>
> 1. the point or place where something begins or is created : the source
>      or cause of something
> 2. the place, social situation, or type of family that a person comes
>      from

Comment: Thanks Ron - but why is it, then, when I looked through eight different computer and networking terminology glossaries online, as well as the classic Tanenbaum/Wetherall "Computer Networks" book, I did not find the term "origin" even defined in, much less used that way? I guess it doesn't really answer the question for me - is that how a user who is setting up network traffic will think of it?

Comment: When you look at layer-2 frames, layer-3 packets, or layer-4 segments, each has source and destination addresses. The origin of a particular datagram is the source address. When you look at a traffic flow, the traffic flows from the origin to the destination. The origin of a network conversation is the one which originated the conversation (usually with a request). It really depends on your perspective.

Comment: @Mattynabib, think about this: You want to listen to a company's earnings call. You dial the number for the conference call on your phone, so you are the origin of the connection. The company CEO and CFO each talk for a long time, giving you the information in which you are interested. From your perspective, each is the origin of that information, even though you are the origin of your connection to the call. To the CEO and CFO, their employees are the origins of the information which they are distributing.